# Replace elements in lists of list prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list like this:

```
board([[16, -,15, -,14, -,13],
       [ -,A, -, -, -,B,-],
       [12, -,11, -,10, -,9],
       [ -, -, -,C, -, -,-],
       [8,  -,7,  -,6,  -,5],
       [- ,D, -, -, -,E,-],
       [4,  -,3,  -, 2, -,1]]).
```

I want to replace in one function elements 16 with 15, 15 with 11, 11 with 12 and 12 with 16. I know how to replace elements in list but i don't know how to do this with this example

The answer should be like this:

```
board([[12, -,16, -,14, -,13],
       [ -,A, -, -, -,B,-],
       [11, -,15, -,10, -,9],
       [ -, -, -,C, -, -,-],
       [8,  -,7,  -,6,  -,5],
       [- ,D, -, -, -,E,-],
       [4,  -,3,  -, 2, -,1]]).
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: This numbers are in circle. I want to rotate the circle and replace first element with second, second with third, third with fourth and fourth with first, but i can't keep this in one list like [16,15,12,11]

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the first thing we need to do is determine how we're going to replace values, the easiest way is to consider these to be functional pairs. Rather than storing a list [16,15,12,11] we can store a list of lists; [[16,15],[15,12],[12,11],[11,16]] this solves our issue in storing what the replace with what. our next step is to break down the input.

```
parse_2d_list([]).

parse_2d_list([H|Tail]) :- %this is my quick parser that breaks it up
  replace_functor(H), %your replacer function
  parse_2d_list(Tail).
```

My example above only outlines the basic parse methodology, you'd likely need additional variables to bind inputs and outputs.

Now we have to search through our list

```
replace_functor([H|Tail],[[Val|Rep]|RTail]],Output,Ac) :- %here I'm using Reps to represent our replacement value    
  H == Val,
  append(Ac,Rep,Ac2),
  replace_functor(Tail,[Val|Rep]|RTail]],Output,Ac2).
```

This only covers a single case. We'd need to smartly determine how to iterate through the replacement list.

An alternative, if you don't want to handle the secondary list, is to use a dynamic.

```
:- dynamic replace/2
```

Here we allow replace/2 to hold the value and its replacement, so if I say

```
assert(replace(16,15)).
```

I've created a fact in my knowledge base to help with binding. We can clean this up at the end by doing

```
retract(replace(16,15)).
```

In that case we can right replace as:

```
replace_functor([H|Tail],Output,Ac) :-
  replace(Val,Rep),
  H == Val,
  append(Ac,Rep,Ac2),
  replace_functor(Tail,Output,Ac2).
```

You'd still need a few differing predicates to clean up this program, but the assertion gives you a lot of pattern matching free.

Hopefully that's enough to get you in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm... in this moment i think that my board is bad written... this should be work like in this image http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/lllgif_enrewhn.gif

Comment: @Bart Yeah, I would order it so the first list in the list is A, the second is B, and so on. You don't need the board letters in your list. On top of that, the capital letters in your list are variables by prolog convention, so you would get some very strange binding.

Comment: So to save this image in lists it'll be look like this: board([[16,15,14,13],[12,11,10,9],[8,7,6,5],[4,3,2,1]]). ? a,b,d,e without c ?

Comment: Well, in your case we still need to store those values to C as well, since it changes those values when it hits C. You might want to assert each region so :- dynamic a/4 .. assert(a(16,15,14,13)). Or something similar.